# Animation for SizeToContent resizing

Tags: wpf, .net-4.0, wpf-controls, sizetocontent

In WPF window, I have specified SizeToContent="WidthAndHeight".
I have a number of panels stacked up, of which I change the visibility (to Visible or Collapsed) as required. My window resizes itself according to the panel that I have set visible. No issues here.

My problem is with the resizing, that the window resizes with a jerk to the final size.
I want to animate this such that the resizing is smooth. And i want to do this in my XAML file.

Is there any solution for this???
P.S. - I have not set any Width or Height property in the window and I want to restrict myself from doing that.